# Routes is declared with name but this.$route.name : undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm using Vue3 CDN on top of a Django project where I added VueRouter and it worked perfectly fine until I decided to add name to the route objects.

Inside of my main component, I'm trying here to check the value of the route name each time the user visite a page.

```
const routes = [
{ 
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: home 
},
{
   path: '/our-program'
   name: 'program',
   component: 'program'
}
]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
// mode: history,
routes,}); 


const app = Vue.createApp({
data() {
    return {}
},
 computed:{
    isFocus(){
        return this.$route.name;
    }
},
mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route);
    },
});

const vm = app.use(router).mount('#pages');
```

I get the path in the console but the $route.name doesn't seem to get through.
Does't anyone know what I've been doing wrong ? [image]

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce it. That `matched` is empty suggests that a route wasn't triggered. Can you navigate these routes in fact?

Comment: Yes I can still navigate through them. 
Only problem is when I try to user the router.name value to handle my styling condition.

Answer (score 0):

this.$route.name can be displayed from the child component not from the actual root component as I was trying to do.